# cc.net svn checkout fails after upgrading to svn 1.7

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I have upgraded my svn client and repo to V 1.7 and now the command generated by cc.net to update the source no longer works.

The command that fails is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CollabNet\Subversion Client\svn.exe log 
svn://localhost/ev_ac/trunk -r "{2011-10-21T09:18:06Z}:{2011-10-21T09:46:56Z}" 
--verbose --xml --username ***** --password ******** --no-auth-cache --non-interactive
```

When i run it manually at the command line i get an error that says:

The procedure entry point svn_diff_mem_string_output_unified2 could not be located in libsvn_diff-1.dll

Anyone else had this problem?  Is this a problem with the svn client or is it that the cc.net command generated is no longer compatible with the current svn client?

Any help or light that could be shed on this would be great as it means that our CI/build server cannot build and deploy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I pointed cc.net at the svn client executable that comes with tortoise svn and it fixed the problem.

Comment: +1 This was very helpful. When you install Tortoise you need to check the optional commandline feature otherwise the svn.exe will not be installed on the machine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The reason was that the old SVN version hadn't been uninstalled automatically before new version installation. You can check it by 'svn.exe --version' command, for me it showed 1.6.12 instead of 1.7.

This was just because PATH environment variable contained two paths - one to old svn folder and another to new svn folder. So removing old svn folder from PATH and manual uninstallation of old SVN fixed the problem (WIN+PAUSE, "Advanced system settings", "Environment variables" button).